# How to catch Slick Events with vue-slick?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, slick.js

It seems like vue-slick does not provide any Events (afterChange, beforeChange, Swipe...) yet. Like it does with the jQuery version.

Should I use `MutationObserver` to listen to `afterChange Event` or someone has a better idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the components, vue-slick *does* fire events. You have `swipe`, `destory`, `afterChange`, `beforeChange` and a lot more.

The list of events were just added 30 mins ago, so check it out: https://github.com/staskjs/vue-slick

for example, to check for `swipe` event you can do:

```
<slick @swipe="handleSwipe">  </slick>
```

Then create a method to get the event data:

```
methods: {
   handleSwipe(event, slick, direction) {
    console.log('handleSwipe', event, slick, direction);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahaha no way, I just watched this doc !